Run connectedAndroidTests without re-installing APK
I have several instrumentation tests that I want to run as part of a build pipeline. I'm assembling and installing the APK on the device in a previous step and don't want it to run through that process for the module again when I run ./gradlew app:cAT, is there an easy way to do that?
I thought I could maybe used the -x flag
-x, --exclude-task                 Specify a task to be excluded from execution.

However running ./gradlew app:cAT -x assembleDebug doesn't appear to work as expected.

If you have already installed the APK using installDebug, you can use connectedAndroidTest (cAT) while excluding the assembleDebug and installDebug tasks like this:
./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -x assembleDebug -x installDebug

